# Nuxt Hot reloading for new components Is not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nodemon, nuxt.js

Nuxt hot reloading somehow works for old components, but any new components that I have created today, doesn't seem to be watched by the app, and doesn't reload. I have to restart the app each time to see the changes applied to these new files.

The machine that I am using is MacOs latest Mojave system.
I realized people might ask for the package.json file so here is the file

```
{
  "name": "theta",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My fabulous Nuxt.js project",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "NUXT_HOST=0.0.0.0 NUXT_PORT=3333 nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "devHttps": "node server/index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@clampy-js/vue-clampy": "^1.0.6",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.9.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.9.0",
    "@nuxtjs/auth": "^4.7.0",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.5.4",
    "@nuxtjs/component-cache": "^1.1.5",
    "@nuxtjs/dotenv": "^1.3.0",
    "@nuxtjs/google-adsense": "^1.1.3",
    "@nuxtjs/google-analytics": "^2.2.0",
    "@nuxtjs/moment": "^1.2.0",
    "@nuxtjs/pwa": "^2.6.0",
    "@nuxtjs/robots": "^2.2.0",
    "@nuxtjs/style-resources": "^0.1.2",
    "@nuxtjs/svg-sprite": "^0.2.1",
    "@nuxtjs/toast": "^3.2.1",
    "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^0.5.6",
    "@sum.cumo/nuxt-styleguide": "^5.3.0",
    "atob": "^2.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "browserslist": "^4.6.2",
    "caniuse-lite": "^1.0.30000974",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "cookie": "^0.3.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.4",
    "cookie-universal-nuxt": "^2.0.16",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "echarts": "^4.2.1",
    "element-ui": "^2.9.1",
    "epic-spinners": "^1.1.0",
    "fstream": "^1.0.12",
    "imagemagick": "^0.1.3",
    "intersection-observer": "^0.5.1",
    "js-yaml": "^3.13.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.11",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "nuxt": "^2.8.1",
    "nuxt-compress": "^1.0.2",
    "nuxt-device-detect": "^1.1.5",
    "nuxt-fontawesome": "^0.4.0",
    "nuxt-stripe-module": "^2.0.0",
    "nuxt-universal-storage": "^0.2.0",
    "nuxt-validate": "^0.1.3",
    "nuxt-webfontloader": "^1.1.0",
    "swiper": "^4.5.0",
    "tar": "^4.4.10",
    "tb-skeleton": "^0.3.6",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "v-charts": "^1.19.0",
    "v-click-outside-x": "^3.7.1",
    "vee-validate": "^2.2.10",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-avatar-editor-improved": "^1.0.4",
    "vue-awesome-swiper": "^3.1.3",
    "vue-chartjs": "^3.4.2",
    "vue-clamp": "^0.2.1",
    "vue-count-to": "^1.0.13",
    "vue-croppa": "^1.3.8",
    "vue-infinite-loading": "^2.4.4",
    "vue-line-clamp": "^1.3.2",
    "vue-loaders": "^2.0.0",
    "vue-match-media": "^1.0.3",
    "vue-scrollama": "^1.1.1",
    "vue-scroller": "^2.2.4",
    "vue-scrollto": "^2.15.0",
    "vue-server-renderer": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-swipe-tab": "^2.0.4",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-text-dot": "^1.0.0",
    "vue-the-mask": "^0.11.1",
    "vue-tiny-lazyload-img": "^0.1.0",
    "vue-truncate-collapsed": "^2.1.0",
    "vue-zondicons": "^0.1.10",
    "vue2-datepicker": "^2.11.2",
    "vue2-editor": "^2.8.1",
    "vue2-touch-events": "^1.1.2",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.2.2",
    "vuetify-upload-button": "^1.2.2",
    "vuex-router-sync": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9.6.0",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "moment-locales-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.7",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.1",
    "postcss-gap-properties": "^2.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2"
  }
}
```

Here is my nuxt config file

```
const pkg = require('./package')
const webpack = require('webpack')
require('dotenv').config()

module.exports = {
  mode: 'universal',

  /*
   ** Headers of the page
   */
  head: {
    title: 'ノーブル',
    meta: [{
        charset: 'utf-8'
      },
      {
        name: 'viewport',
        content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1'
      },
      {
        hid: 'description',
        name: 'description',
        content: '小説家・読者のプラットフォーム'
      }
    ],
    link: [{
      rel: 'icon',
      type: 'image/x-icon',
      href: '/favicon.ico'
    }],
    script: [{
      src: '/js/fb-sdk.js'
    }, {
      src: '/js/gg-sdk.js'
    }]
  },

  /*
   ** Customize the progress-bar color
   */
  loading: {

    color: '#af9bd0',
    height: '3px',
    continuous: true
  },
  generate: {
    routes: [
      '/ads.txt',
    ]
  },
  /*
   ** Global CSS
   */
  css: [
    'element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css',
    'swiper/dist/css/swiper.css',
    "assets/css/index.css",
    "assets/css/main.scss",
    'vue-loaders/dist/vue-loaders.css'
  ],

  /*
   ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
   */
  plugins: [
    '@/plugins/element-ui',
    '@/plugins/intercept',
    {
      src: '~plugins/vue-star-rating',
      ssr: false
    },
    {
      src: '~/plugins/swiper',
      ssr: false
    },
    {
      src: '~/plugins/intercept',
      ssr: false
    },
    {
      ssr: false,
      src: '~/plugins/avatar'
    },
    {
      ssr: false,
      src: "~plugins/clickOutside"
    }, {
      ssr: false,
      src: "~plugins/vueEditor"
    }, {
      src: '@/plugins/vueMask',
      ssr: false
    }, {
      src: '@/plugins/zondiIcon',
      ssr: false
    }, {
      src: '@/plugins/elementLoading',
      ssr: false
    }, {
      src: '@/plugins/vue-swipe-tab',
      ssr: false
    },
    {
      src: '@/plugins/pull-to',
      ssr: false
    },
    {
      src: '@/plugins/datePicker',
      ssr: false
    }, {
      src: '@/plugins/vuelineclamp',
      ssr: false
    }, {
      src: '@/plugins/graphs',
      ssr: false
    }, {
      src: '@/plugins/infinite',
      ssr: false
    }, {
      src: '@/plugins/vueClamp',
      ssr: false
    }, {
      src: '@/plugins/watchMedia',
      ssr: false
    }, {
      src: '@/plugins/scrollama',
      ssr: false
    }, {
      src: '@/plugins/countTo',
      ssr: false
    }, {
      src: '@/plugins/chartLine',
      ssr: false
    }, {
      src: '@/plugins/skeleton',
      ssr: false
    }, {
      src: '@/plugins/gAuth',
      ssr: false,
    }, {
      src: '@/plugins/epicSpinners',
      ssr: false,
    },
    {
      src: '@/plugins/auth',
    }

  ],

  /*
   ** Nuxt.js modules
   */
  modules: [
    ['@nuxtjs/vuetify', {
      treeShake: true
    }],
    '@nuxtjs/pwa',
    'nuxt-device-detect',
    'nuxt-webfontloader',
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/dotenv',
    '@nuxtjs/svg-sprite',
    '@nuxtjs/style-resources',

    ['nuxt-validate', {
      lang: 'ja',
    }],
    ['@nuxtjs/robots', {
      UserAgent: '*',
      Disallow: '/',
      UserAgent: 'Googlebot',
      Disallow: '',
      UserAgent: 'Yahoo-slurp',
      Disallow: '',
      UserAgent: 'Msnbot',
      Disallow: ''
    }],
    ['@nuxtjs/moment', {
      locales: ['ja'],
      defaultLocale: 'ja'
    }],
    ['@nuxtjs/component-cache', {
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60
    }],
    ['@nuxtjs/google-adsense', {
      id: 'pub-4438410171989811'
    }],
    'cookie-universal-nuxt',
    ['nuxt-fontawesome', {
      component: 'fa',
      imports: [{
        set: '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons',
        icons: ['fas']
      }, {
        set: '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons',
        icons: ['fab']
      }]
    }],
    ['@nuxtjs/google-analytics', {
      id: 'UA-119733183-2',
      autoTracking: {
        page: false
      }
    }],
    ['nuxt-universal-storage', {
      storage: {
        vuex: true, // boolean or {namespace} 
        localStorage: true, // boolean or {prefix } 
        cookie: true, // boolean or {prefix, options } 
        initialState: {}, // Object {}
        ignoreExceptions: true // 
      }
    }],
    ['@nuxtjs/dotenv', {
      /* module options */
    }],
    ['@nuxtjs/toast', {
      position: 'top-right',
      duration: 5000
    }],
    ['nuxt-stripe-module', {
      publishableKey: process.env.STRIPE_KEY,
      version: 'v3', // Default
    }],
    "nuxt-compress",
  ],
  /*
   ** Axios module configuration
   */
  axios: {
    baseURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://0.0.0.0:5000/api',
    credentials: false,
    proxyHeaders: false
  },

  auth: {
    strategies: {
      google: {
        client_id: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        user: false,
        redirect_uri: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/'
      },
      facebook: {
        client_id: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID,
        userinfo_endpoint: false,
        scope: ['public_profile', 'email'],
        redirect_uri: 'https://tolocalhost.com/'
      },
      local: {
        _scheme: '~/auth/local.js',
        endpoints: {
          login: {
            url: 'auth/login',
            method: 'post',
            propertyName: false
          },
          user: {
            url: 'user/show',
            method: 'get',
            propertyName: false
          },
          logout: false
        }
      }
    },
    redirect: {
      login: '/auth/login',
      logout: '/',
      callback: '/',
      home: '/'
    },
    plugins: ['~/plugins/auth.js']
  },
  router: {
    middleware: ['auth'],
    linkActiveClass: 'active-link'
  },
  webfontloader: {
    google: {
      families: ['IBM Plex Sans:300,400,700', 'Noto Sans JP:400,500', 'Sniglet:400,800'] //Loads Lato font with weights 400 and 700
    }
  },
  'manifest': {
    name: 'ノーブル　小説',
    short_name: 'ノーブル',
    lang: 'ja'
  },
  /*
   ** Build configuration
   */
  build: {
    /*
     ** You can extend webpack config here
     */
    extend(config, ctx) {

    },
    splitChunks: {
      layouts: true
    },
    styleResources: {
      sass: ['./assets/css/abstracts/main.scss']
    },
    transpile: ['vue-clamp', 'resize-detector'],
    postcss: {
      plugins: [
        require('postcss-gap-properties')(),
        require('autoprefixer')({
          grid: true,
          flexbox: true,
          stats: {
            warnings: false
          }
        })
      ]

    },
    plugins: [new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
    })]
  },
  server: {
    port: process.env.CLIENT_PORT || 4000, // default: 3000
    host: process.env.API_HOST || '0.0.0.0', // default: localhost
  },
}
```

I've searched everywhere online for the answer but none that seemed close to my current situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh I got it, it seems like there was a misspelling in importing of the component, and thus wasn't connected to the main nuxt network, meaning  the component doesn't adhere to the hot reloading watched file.

Answer (score 0):

Had the problem of hot reload not working.
Solved that by adding

```
  watchers: {
    webpack: {
      aggregateTimeout: 300,
      poll: 1000
    }
  }
```

in the nuxt.config.js file.